# Odds Ratio from Sample size, mean and SD

Tags: standard-deviation, mean, odds-ratio

I do have the following data

```
TABLE A
Population Size | Type    | Value
340             | Control | .7+03[SD]
350             | Test    | .015+.25[SD]
```

Can I convert this to something like this? How ?

```
TABLE B
Population Size | Type    | Value
340             | Control | 25
350             | Test    | 33
```

If not how to I convert TABLE A into a Odds Ratio (based on Mean and SD only)

Answer (score 1):

It would be possible if the mean is the mean of a binary variable coded using the values 0 or 1. In that case, the mean would actually be the proportion of 1s. In that case the odds of a 1 would be $\frac{0.7}{1-0.7}\approx 2.3$, i.e. within the control group we expect to find 2.3 1s for ever 0. The odds of a 1 for the test group would be $\frac{0.015}{1-0.015}\approx 0.015$. The odds ratio would than be just the ratio of those odds: $\frac{\frac{.7}{1-.7}}{\frac{0.015}{1-0.015}} = \frac{0.7}{1-0.7} \times \frac{1-0.015}{0.015}= \frac{0.7(1-0.015)}{(1-0.7)0.015}\approx153$, that is the odds of a 1 in the control group is a 153 times larger than the odds of a 1 in the test group.

However, your means are **not** proportions, so this method won't work for you. I know this because if the mean for the control group were a proportion, then the standard deviation would have been $\sqrt{0.7*(1-0.7)}\approx0.46$, which is completely different from the standard deviation you report in the table.

If you want to find out if there is anything possible, then we need to know more about your problem: In particular what is your dependent variable and how is it measured?

Comment: Thanks Maarten, actually the value that I have is cholesterol level for each of the population (with drug and control sets).  so, yes the means are not proportions. Here is

Comment: Here are actual values
<pre>
348       Placebo           0.07+0.15 [SD]
339       Ra20mg          0.17+0.2 [SD]
114       Placebo            0.3+0.68 [SD]
114       Oxxxx20mg      -0.05+0.76 [SD]
</pre>

Comment: So the dependent variable is not binary?

Comment: No, they are not.

Comment: Then the whole concept of Odds Ratio does not make sense for your problem. So it cannot be computed.